# Prove that for any real or complex scalar $\lambda$ the set $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R} ^n$ or $\mathbb{C} ^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real or complex matrix . Prove that for any real or complex scalar $\lambda$ the set $S = \{x : Ax = \lambda x \}$ is a subspace of  $\mathbb{R} ^n$ or $\mathbb{C} ^n$.

So I see that this should be true (seems even trivial?) but have no idea how to prove a set to be a subspace.. Should i show that every $x$ is in either $\mathbb{R} ^n$ or $\mathbb{C} ^n$?

Any hints would be helpful..

Comment: No, you need to show 1) $0 \in S$, 2) $x,y \in S \Rightarrow x+y\in S$, 3) $x \in S, c \in \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow c\cdot x \in S$ (replace $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @DanielFischer But $x$ is a vector? So why do you state $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$? Shouldn't it be $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: $x \in S \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$). So when you multiply that vector with a scalar, the scalar comes from $\mathbb{C}$ (resp. $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Doh! I managed to think that you meant the vectors, but you were talking about the constant.. Thanks for the statement

Answer (score 2):

So following the guidelines Daniel gave, we prove the three properties of a subspace:

(1) $0 \in S$, trivially true.

(2) For any two eigenvectors $x,y$ we want to show that $x+y \in S$; we have $Ax = \lambda x \: \: and \: \: Ay = \lambda y.$ Which means, $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay = \lambda x + \lambda y = \lambda(x+y)$, thus $x+y \in S$.

(3) Furthermore, $A(cx) = c(Ax) = c(\lambda x) = \lambda (cx)$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$. So $cx \in S$ and hence $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$ in case of $c \in \mathbb{C}$).

Answer (score 0):

Write $S= \{x| (A-\lambda I) x = 0\} = \operatorname{ker}(A-\lambda I)$ and thus, as the kernel of a Homomorphism, a subspace.

Comment: If you could explain to me how I should use the definition of a Homomorphism to conclude your answer..?

Comment: If you have not yet proven that the kernel of a homomorphism is a subspace, you can disregard my answer.